# How to make a deep copy of a list of strings in emacs lisp?

Tags: list, emacs

I need to make a deep copy of a list of strings. Result should be another list of strings, that are distinct of the strings in the first list, but have same length and consist of the same characters.

However, standard functions, such as `copy-list`, `copy-sequence`, `copy-tree` all, it seems, make shallow copies, that is they share strings between two lists.

Comment: Why?  In my experience, you're almost always much better off treating strings as read-only objects (which hence never need copying).

Comment: I am applying different coloring on the same ascii picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to innovate:

```
(mapcar #'copy-sequence list-of-strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed the same elements but temporarily add a new element on the end of the list and `(copy-sequence)` worked for that, all elements except one in the list were shallow copies and the last one was a new entity. The original list was not modified by that.